# Access QCustomPlot Variable

Tags: c++, qt, private, qcustomplot

**In Short:**

I need to access a QCustomPlot variable in a WidgetClass. But I can't because it's private in that context. How is this accomplished?

**What I have done:**

I have a class that creates a graph and a widget class that calls the graph class 
My QCustomPlot variable is a private variable that is being declared in the graph class, but  I need to access this variable in the Widget Class.

I have a generate_graphs slot that gets data and passes the data to the graph class and from there the graph is created. I am saving to a png, so I need to access the graph variable with this data, the variable is passed data in the WidgetClass which then calls the graph class, which generates the graph.

The graph class variable (in the Widget Class) is declared like so: `GraphWidget* graph`
I try to access the QCustomPlot variable in that slot like this: `graph->QCustomPlot->savePNG()`
I keep getting an error that says `QCustomPlot* GraphWidget::QCustomPlot is private within this context`

I then created a function to just return the `GraphWidget* graph` so I could access that variable in the graph class. Instead so I could access the QCustomPlot variable without it being private in that context. This caused errors because it needs to be passed a `GraphWidget* graph` which is not declared in the GraphWidget class.

Comment: Since it is private you can either 1) use it inside the `graph` instance or expose it outside the `graph` instance. Following the first approach, you can define a public `savePng()` inside your `GraphWidget` and call from that code `customPlotInstace->savePNG()`. By the way, is it `QCustomPlot` an instance name? That seems weird.

Comment: `QCustomPlot` is the variable type, the `QCustomPlot` variable is declared in the GraphWidget Class, but I want to access it in the WidgetClass. I have done what you suggested, however the data that I want to save to a png is defined in the WidgetClass. The WidgetClass gets data gives it to the GraphClass and the GraphClass generates a graph, the GraphClass does not save data, I want to create a png of the graph, this graph (with data) is in the WidgetClass, not the GraphClass. Ideally I would not have to do anything in the GraphClass at all. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ooook...without code that's guessing. Sorry but, by reading your text, it is not so clear who is who. In any case, the solution is always one: provide a public method (or a chain of methods) to reach a context where the resource can be used, in this case the `QCustomPlot`. When you say "the data I want to save" you mean another `QCustomPlot`? It that's the case, just put the public function with `QCustomPlot->savePNG()` where this other instance is located.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I understand, I wanted to put code, but it's mixed up with so much other unrelated code it'd be more confusing. Right now, Everything I'm working with is Private. I'll try making it public. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you don't want to do all this saving stuff in your `GraphWidget` class, create a getter method in your `GraphWidget` class that returns a `QCustomPlot *`. So something like `QCustomPlot* GraphWidget::getCustomPlot(){ return customPlot;}`. Though I think the better solution is like BaCaRoZzo suggested, define a public `savePng(...)` method inside your `GraphWidget` class in which you would call `customPlot->savePng(...)`.

Comment: You also say *however the data that I want to save to a png is defined in the WidgetClass...*. `QCustomPlot` contains this data, this is the data that you will save. You don't pass any data to the `QCustomPlot::savePng(...)` method because it already has the data. So I don't know what you meant by that sentence.

Comment: @thuga I could be over thinking this, but what I meant was data is passed to the WidgetClass which then creates a GraphClass variable and passes the data to the GraphClass variable which then creates a Graph. I want to use that GraphClass variable that the WidgetClass creates to make the png file. I have been able to create a png file through the GraphWidget class, however it does not contain any data.

Comment: Could you post some code, not all of it, just these parts where you create the graph, pass data to it, and save it as png?

Comment: @thuga I actually ended up solving it, I did have to make a public function. Where I was going wrong was I was trying to pass around the GraphWidget variable around the Widget Class, I had to make it so that the GraphWidget variable was a class variable. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an isolated problem, but if anyone else has a similar problem my suggestion is this:

Make sure that your GraphWidget variable (the variable to creates a `QCustomPlot`) is accessible by the entire class that is trying to use it. I was trying to pass it a bunch of different ways, and none of them were correct.

Also make sure you create a **public** function in the GraphWidget class in order to access the savePng() function that `QCustomPlot` uses.